# How to read a variable creating html with python

Tags: python

I got this in python

```
Name = input("type the Name: ")
Last_Name = input("Type the lastname: ")
ID = input("Type the ID: ")
folder = "c:\\xfiles"
if os.path.exists(folder) == False:
os.mkdir(folder)
html = open(folder+"\\"+"Homework"+".html", "w")
html.write('<html>')
html.write('    <head>')
html.write('    </head>')
html.write('    <body>')
html.write('        <center>')
html.write('            <table border=10 cellspacing=0 cellspacing=2>')
html.write('                <tr>')
html.write('                    <td>ID:</td>')
html.write('                    <td>ID</td>') #Here trying to call but it just show me "ID"
html.write('                </tr>')
html.write('        </center>')
html.write('    </body>')
html.write('</html>')
html.close()
```

When i try to call the variable "ID", it does not appear, any reason or any help to fix this?

Comment: how come space between last and name.. it should be last_name

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: im using 3.4.0 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to actually put the variable into the string by using something like format in order for it to show up. Using something like your original approach you would have to change this:

```
html.write('                    <td>%s</td>' % ID) #"ID" now using the variable
```

But if you are making a HTML template then I presume you want to substitute a bunch of different string. Having to doing this all the time on a line by line basis would get quite annoying so I'd suggest doing something like this to make the process more manageable:

```
first_name = input("type the Name: ")
last_name = input("Type the lastname: ")
ID = input("Type the ID: ")

template = """<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <table border=10 cellspacing=0 cellspacing=2>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID:</td>
                    <td>{ID}</td> <-- Now we are actually accessing the variable here
                </tr>
        </center>
    </body>
 </html>
""" 
context = {
 "first_name": first_name, 
 "last_name": last_name,
 "ID": ID,
 } 
with  open('homework.html','w') as myfile:
    myfile.write(template.format(**context))
```

Comment: @user3691177: Then what *does* happen? Do you get an exception, was `{ID}` written to the file instead of the entered id? There were some name errors in the answer which I corrected, but it would have been helpful if you'd mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your code. You are writing the ID as string to the html file not the value of ID.

```
html.write('                    <td>'+ID+'</td>') #it prints the value of ID
```

Comment: please use `%s` string interpolation or `.format()`